# OM3 Fiber connections

Tags: networking, windows-10, switch, fortigate

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read my issue.

Let me start off with I am in school for programming and my networking skills are limited. However, I have started an internship for a company and have been working to fix their network/server issues.

So the problem I have been facing for a few days and cant seem to figure anything out is we have a switch running to the back of the building to connect to the network from back there and its running to the server room from an OM3 fiber cable.

When I go look at the switch it has power and the lights are on and seems to be working. I followed the cable to the server room and it's connected to its own "box" in the server room for an OM3 fiber cable. We currently use Fortigate for our network monitoring, on Fortigate it shows the switch however it's showing as offline and not active. The other 4 switches in the server room are daisy chained together are working. So I am thinking that there should be another cable coming to the server that plugs into the other switches as a daisy chain as well as the OM3 cable? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Joshua McDaniel

Comment: By "its own box" do you mean a media converter? (Two ports total, fiber port on one end, regular copper Ethernet port on the other end.)

Comment: Honestly about the box I am not exactly sure but it's got a glass panel on top that says the laser warnings (which is on the end with the server (but does not actually plug into the server)) and then on the back side of the building is the Ethernet end where the switch is set up.

Comment: @Nerdscript - How about model numbers?  Without specifics this question will be nearly impossible to answer